# QGIS Georeferencer Hangs

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I am trying to georeference an image in QGIS version 3.18. It did run on the first attempt but I wasn't happy with the (linear) transformation. Unlike previous threads it doesn't produce an error - just hangs with "Progress Indication Not responding". I have waited for over an our. The file it produces is only 3k.
[image: Progress Indication not repsonding]

I have deleted and retried numerous different GCP points and both tif and png images. The output resolution is unticked. I will paste the GCP table below but it looks OK to me?? I am using Polynomial 2 transform and nearest neighbor.

[image: CGP Table]

Answer (score 1):

uninstalled 3.18 and installed 3.16. Re-ran. Polynomial 2 now produces a "Can't Compute Error" , however Polynomial 1 worked fine with suitable accuracy...